# BlueZ MediaPlayer track position not synced with phone

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, a2dp

I have paired my Android phone with Ubuntu 18.04.1 and playing music on phone(the a2dp source). I can hear music on Ubuntu(the a2dp sink), send commands to phone (such as Play/Pause/Next etc) using `dbus` and `media api` of BlueZ and also get track info ( Title, Duration, track Position, etc.)

The problem:If I am playing a song of duration say 5min currently at 2:10, dbus query gives me correct Position of around 130000ms, but if I manually change the position on phone to say suppose 2:30, dbus query still shows time of around 130-140k ms which means it is calculating the position on its own based on last sync, and unaware of any changes made from phone. However, if I pause and play again, the position is synced again and shows correct position.

The dbus query:

```
    dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_C3_46_7B_2D_C7/player0 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:"org.bluez.MediaPlayer1" string:"Position"
```

I decided to cross check with Windows 10 `a2dp sink player`, but there the change in track position from phone is immediately reflected to player window.
I tried monitoring dbus signals with:

```
dbus-monitor --system "type='signal', sender='org.bluez'"
```

And this was the output:

```
dbus-monitor: unable to enable new-style monitoring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: "Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.246" (uid=1000 pid=8991 comm="dbus-monitor --system type='signal', sender='org.b" label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring" member="BecomeMonitor" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)". Falling back to eavesdropping.
signal time=1555847560.121045 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.246 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.246"
signal time=1555847570.624003 sender=:1.161 -> destination=(null destination) serial=32467 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_C3_46_7B_2D_C7/fd1; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.MediaTransport1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "State"
         variant             string "pending"
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
signal time=1555847570.625959 sender=:1.161 -> destination=(null destination) serial=32469 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_C3_46_7B_2D_C7/fd1; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.MediaTransport1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "State"
         variant             string "active"
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
signal time=1555847570.662250 sender=:1.161 -> destination=(null destination) serial=32470 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_C3_46_7B_2D_C7/player0; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.MediaPlayer1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "Status"
         variant             string "playing"
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
signal time=1555847570.723943 sender=:1.161 -> destination=(null destination) serial=32471 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_C3_46_7B_2D_C7/player0; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.MediaPlayer1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "Position"
         variant             uint32 148405
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

Which confirms that `PropertiesChanged` signal is fired only when actions such Play/Pause/Next/Previous are executed, and not when position is changed on phone.

Can I make BlueZ fire the `PropertiesChanged` signal whenever I want, probably using BlueZ api itself?